# How to set global variable with method

Tags: python

```
abc  = None

def load() :
   abc  = cPickle.load('a.pkl')

load()

def main(review):
   print abc.predict('example')
```

The variable `abc` is still set to `None`.  `main` is accessing `abc` many times and I don't want to load the file every time. How can I load the contents of the file once?

Comment: `global` keyword :)

Comment: You could use `global` but that's not the way how it should be done. Use a return value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `global` keyword

```
abc  = None

def load() :
   global abc
   abc  = cPickle.load('a.pkl')

load()

def main(review):
   print abc.predict('example')
```

Without `global` interpreter will create a new local variable `tested` in function scope.
But better to use `return` statement and local variables like

```
def load() :
   return cPickle.load('a.pkl')

def main(review):
   abc = load()
   print abc.predict('example')
```

Comment: Is that a right approach am I using??

Comment: @lucy Please, see updates

Comment: main fun is calling thousand of time. I don't want to load file every time.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a global variable with `global myvariable`